# Viewing deeper properties from JSON

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have some code where I verify the people born between 1900 and 1925. Great, however obviously when I console.log it, it returns the three objects with all its properties and its prototype. Is there any way I can get it so simply console one specific property? Say for example I dont want to display all three objects I just want it to show the name of the people born between 1900-1925. Thanks!

```
var ANCESTRY_FILE = "[\n  " + [
  '{"name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1832, "died": 1905, "father": "Carel Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria van Brussel"}',
  '{"name": "Emma de Milliano", "sex": "f", "born": 1876, "died": 1956, "father": "Petrus de Milliano", "mother": "Sophia van Damme"}',
  '{"name": "Maria de Rycke", "sex": "f", "born": 1683, "died": 1724, "father": "Frederik de Rycke", "mother": "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"}',
  '{"name": "Jan van Brussel", "sex": "m", "born": 1714, "died": 1748, "father": "Jacobus van Brussel", "mother": "Joanna van Rooten"}',
  '{"name": "Philibert Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1907, "died": 1997, "father": "Emile Haverbeke", "mother": "Emma de Milliano"}',
  '{"name": "Jan Frans van Brussel", "sex": "m", "born": 1761, "died": 1833, "father": "Jacobus Bernardus van Brussel", "mother":null}',
  '{"name": "Pauwels van Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1535, "died": 1582, "father": "N. van Haverbeke", "mother":null}',
  '{"name": "Clara Aernoudts", "sex": "f", "born": 1918, "died": 2012, "father": "Henry Aernoudts", "mother": "Sidonie Coene"}',
  '{"name": "Emile Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1877, "died": 1968, "father": "Carolus Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria Sturm"}',
  '{"name": "Lieven de Causmaecker", "sex": "m", "born": 1696, "died": 1724, "father": "Carel de Causmaecker", "mother": "Joanna Claes"}',
  '{"name": "Pieter Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1602, "died": 1642, "father": "Lieven van Haverbeke", "mother":null}',
  '{"name": "Livina Haverbeke", "sex": "f", "born": 1692, "died": 1743, "father": "Daniel Haverbeke", "mother": "Joanna de Pape"}',
  '{"name": "Pieter Bernard Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1695, "died": 1762, "father": "Willem Haverbeke", "mother": "Petronella Wauters"}',
  '{"name": "Lieven van Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1570, "died": 1636, "father": "Pauwels van Haverbeke", "mother": "Lievijne Jans"}',
  '{"name": "Joanna de Causmaecker", "sex": "f", "born": 1762, "died": 1807, "father": "Bernardus de Causmaecker", "mother":null}',
  '{"name": "Willem Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1668, "died": 1731, "father": "Lieven Haverbeke", "mother": "Elisabeth Hercke"}',
  '{"name": "Pieter Antone Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1753, "died": 1798, "father": "Jan Francies Haverbeke", "mother": "Petronella de Decker"}',
  '{"name": "Maria van Brussel", "sex": "f", "born": 1801, "died": 1834, "father": "Jan Frans van Brussel", "mother": "Joanna de Causmaecker"}',
  '{"name": "Angela Haverbeke", "sex": "f", "born": 1728, "died": 1734, "father": "Pieter Bernard Haverbeke", "mother": "Livina de Vrieze"}',
  '{"name": "Elisabeth Haverbeke", "sex": "f", "born": 1711, "died": 1754, "father": "Jan Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria de Rycke"}',
  '{"name": "Lievijne Jans", "sex": "f", "born": 1542, "died": 1582, "father":null, "mother":null}',
  '{"name": "Bernardus de Causmaecker", "sex": "m", "born": 1721, "died": 1789, "father": "Lieven de Causmaecker", "mother": "Livina Haverbeke"}',
  '{"name": "Jacoba Lammens", "sex": "f", "born": 1699, "died": 1740, "father": "Lieven Lammens", "mother": "Livina de Vrieze"}',
  '{"name": "Pieter de Decker", "sex": "m", "born": 1705, "died": 1780, "father": "Joos de Decker", "mother": "Petronella van de Steene"}',
  '{"name": "Joanna de Pape", "sex": "f", "born": 1654, "died": 1723, "father": "Vincent de Pape", "mother": "Petronella Wauters"}',
  '{"name": "Daniel Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1652, "died": 1723, "father": "Lieven Haverbeke", "mother": "Elisabeth Hercke"}',
  '{"name": "Lieven Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1631, "died": 1676, "father": "Pieter Haverbeke", "mother": "Anna van Hecke"}',
  '{"name": "Martina de Pape", "sex": "f", "born": 1666, "died": 1727, "father": "Vincent de Pape", "mother": "Petronella Wauters"}',
  '{"name": "Jan Francies Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1725, "died": 1779, "father": "Pieter Bernard Haverbeke", "mother": "Livina de Vrieze"}',
  '{"name": "Maria Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1905, "died": 1997, "father": "Emile Haverbeke", "mother": "Emma de Milliano"}',
  '{"name": "Petronella de Decker", "sex": "f", "born": 1731, "died": 1781, "father": "Pieter de Decker", "mother": "Livina Haverbeke"}',
  '{"name": "Livina Sierens", "sex": "f", "born": 1761, "died": 1826, "father": "Jan Sierens", "mother": "Maria van Waes"}',
  '{"name": "Laurentia Haverbeke", "sex": "f", "born": 1710, "died": 1786, "father": "Jan Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria de Rycke"}',
  '{"name": "Carel Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1796, "died": 1837, "father": "Pieter Antone Haverbeke", "mother": "Livina Sierens"}',
  '{"name": "Elisabeth Hercke", "sex": "f", "born": 1632, "died": 1674, "father": "Willem Hercke", "mother": "Margriet de Brabander"}',
  '{"name": "Jan Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1671, "died": 1731, "father": "Lieven Haverbeke", "mother": "Elisabeth Hercke"}',
  '{"name": "Anna van Hecke", "sex": "f", "born": 1607, "died": 1670, "father": "Paschasius van Hecke", "mother": "Martijntken Beelaert"}',
  '{"name": "Maria Sturm", "sex": "f", "born": 1835, "died": 1917, "father": "Charles Sturm", "mother": "Seraphina Spelier"}',
  '{"name": "Jacobus Bernardus van Brussel", "sex": "m", "born": 1736, "died": 1809, "father": "Jan van Brussel", "mother": "Elisabeth Haverbeke"}'
].join(",\n  ") + "\n]";

// This makes sure the data is exported in node.js —
var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE);
function filter(array,test){
    passed = [];

    for ( i = 0 ; i < ancestry.length ; i++){
        if(test(array[i])){
            passed.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return passed;
}


console.log(filter(ancestry,function(person){ return person.born > 1900 && person.born < 1925;}));
```

Comment: So just push that property value to array...not complicated. Or in the view only show `person.name`

Comment: @charlietfl, got it thanks. For some reason I was thinking too complicated.

Comment: Please don't immediately ask questions without thinking them through a bit. This question will have no long term value to anyone

Comment: I did think for about 15-20  minutes, and I tried 4 or 5 things before asking, it didn't occur to me that obvious solution until you said it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply made an array `s = []`, and appended `person.name`in an if statement. Thanks guys, I was thinking too hard.